# how secure is an iframe

Tags: security, iframe, portal, intranet

I'm in the process of making a portal website and I wanted to include an iframe which would route people to an intranet. Is there any downsides to this as far as security is concerned?

Answer (score 1):

It is no more or less secure than giving those people direct web access to that intranet.

If you really want to know whether something is "secure" or not, you need to specify the types of threat that you need to protect against, what your tolerance is for breaks in that security, and what additional mechanisms that you have taken to secure your site (for example password authentication, NTLM, SSL, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I think that maybe there's a misunderstanding on your side regarding the function of IFrames: An `<iframe>` will not **route** anything. It just tells the user's browser which URL to fetch and show inside it. This means that

1. People need access to the intranet to actually load the contents of the `<iframe>`, which might not be what you expected.
2. It's not a security risk per se.